# phonegap js library cannot run on File:// url

Tags: javascript, cordova

i got a problem the thing is that I'm trying to use a js library that can't be run locally I mean with a File:// URL, I think that I'm not the only one with this problem since there are a bunch of js libraries that need to be on a server in order to work for example phaserjs if anyone can give me an idea on how to accomplish this task I will be really grateful

Answer (score 0):

In Your config.xml, have you set :

```
<access origin="*" />
```

It allows you to load files / access any external url.

Comment: Are you sure that this work for File:// ? What im trying to achieve is access to a .json file on my www folder.

Comment: Are you trying to load a file on your /www folder, or from an external url ? If its from /www just load it from its path like you normally would on an html page.

Comment: its not working hiving me this error : `[phonegap] [console.error] Failed to retrieve manifest: No resolvers to handle url: ["file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E7E9CC28-7431-4EB
7-B5EC-5B31676AE8D3/Library/files/phonegapdevapp/www/index.html","counter.json"]`